# "Be offered" vs "get offered"

Tags: passive-voice

What is the difference between the two in the title? E.g. be offered a job or get offered a job? Is "get offered" even grammatically correct? And why?

I have a feeling that the first one sounds natural but I can't find the evidence of the second one being incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get** is grammatically correct, but **be** is very much more common in passive voice sentences. This NGram graph shows that usage of **get** is negligible with **offered**.

**get** is normally used to indicate a change of state, whereas **be** is used to indicate being in a state. For example, **get ready** is what you do to change from not ready to ready, whereas **be ready** suggests that you have been ready for a while.

**get** is far more likely to be used in passive voice sentences in circumstances where somebody is seen as a victim of circumstance (got hit by a car, got dumped). See this NGram graph and note that i) **was** is still a lot more common than **got** ii) **got** is more common in US English than British English.

**get** may be more common in informal British English, but that's hard to prove.